# Github runner not installing requirements.txt file in lamda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, github-actions, fastapi, requirements.txt

The github runner shows that it completes the jobs correctly however when I run them I am getting an error showing that fastapi is not installed it is in the requirements.txt file

here is the yaml file I am using

```
 name: API CI/CD

 on:
   # Trigger the workflow on push
   push:
     branches:
       # Push events on main branch
       - main

 # The Job defines a series of steps that execute on the same runner.

 jobs:
   CI:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
       - uses: actions/checkout@v2

       - name: Set up Python
         uses: actions/setup-python@v2
         with:
           python-version: 3.9

       - name: Install dependencies
         run: pip3 install -r ./app/requirements.txt

       - name: Create application ZIP archive
         run: cd ./app && zip -r app.zip .

       - name: Upload app.zip artifact
         uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
         with:
           name: app
           path: ./app/app.zip

       - name: Upload swagger.json artifact
         uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
         with:
           name: swagger
           path: ./app/swagger.json

    CD:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: [ CI ]
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
      steps:
         - name: Install AWS CLI
           uses: unfor19/install-aws-cli-action@v1
          with:
             version: 1
          env:
             AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
             AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
             AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

        - name: Download Lambda app.zip
          uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
          with:
            name: app

        - name: Download swagger.json artifact
          uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
          with:
             name: swagger

        - name: Upload app.zip to S3
           run: aws s3 cp app.zip s3://telidexapigithubdeploy/app.zip
           env:
             AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
             AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
             AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

        - name: Upload swagger.json to S3
           run: aws s3 cp swagger.json s3://telidexapiswaggerjson/swagger.json
          env:
             AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
             AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
             AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

         - name: Deploy new Lambda
           run: aws lambda update-function-code --function-name telidexapi --s3-bucket telidexapigithubdeploy --s3-key app.zip
           env:
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
```

here is the aws errors:

```
       ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   timestamp   |                                                                               
  message                                                                                
  |
  |---------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   | 1692052249122 | INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.9.v26 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:130681a0855afedf31b2b3fbcc2fbf1ca62875e0500edb56fd16cad65045b05b   |
   | 1692052249226 | START RequestId: 9a247ffa-5364-4eb5-9596-e1015c45bd84 Version: $LATEST                                                                                               
   |
   | 1692052249226 | [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'fastapi' Traceback (most recent call last):                                      
   |
   | 1692052249228 | END RequestId: 9a247ffa-5364-4eb5-9596-e1015c45bd84                                                                                                                  
   |
   | 1692052249228 | REPORT RequestId: 9a247ffa-5364-4eb5-9596-e1015c45bd84 Duration: 2.36 ms Billed Duration: 3 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB Init Duration: 103.49 ms   |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Its gotta be in the deploy step of the CD but I am not sure what I am doing wrong Ive tried a bunch of different tutorials same result

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it turned out the requirements where installed on the container default Python and not on the new version. I solved it by adding `python -m` to the command

```
- name: Set up Python 3.11
  uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: 3.11

- name: Install requirements
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    python -m pip install -r ./app/requirements.txt
```

Comment: This is showing promise as I am not seeing the errors again however I still need to troubleshoot some access token issues I will report back with more

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share more of the log related to the `Install dependencies` step? I'd like to confirm whether FastAPI is installed.

Speculation:

1. Installation of FastAPI might have encountered an error or been skipped.
2. FastAPI might not be included in the `requirements.txt`.

If possible, I would appreciate more detailed logs from the `Install dependencies` step to better understand whether FastAPI was indeed installed or if there were any issues during the process.